# subprocess.call fails whereas manual execution works

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to execute the following command

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "fontsample - Latin Modern Family.tex"
```

which works from the console flawless.

In python I execute the following code

```
tex.callSystemCommand(['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-shell-escape', '"' + filename + '.tex"'])

def callSystemCommand(command):
    try:
        retcode = subprocess.call(command) # shell=True
        if retcode != 0:
            print("System command was terminated by signal", -retcode, file=sys.stderr)
            sys.exit()
    except OSError as e:
        print("Execution failed:", e, file=sys.stderr)
```

which fails with -1. I would like to know what is exactly executed.

EDIT:
The execution works fine with

```
    executeCode = 'pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape "' \
                 + filename + '"'
    os.system(executeCode)
```

Comment: I suspect you don't need the quotation marks around your filename. Those are only needed on the command line because the shell needs to know where to break up the arguments. With `subprocess`, the separate strings do that already.

Comment: @Alp: How could I get the error message?

Comment: I gave answer to quite similar question in ["Passing parameters to Python subprocess.Popen"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21299292/2419207). Maybe it gives you some  ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command probably fails because it cannot find a file named `"somefilename"`. Usually, the shell will process the parameter enclosed in `"`, strip them and pass the filename (with spaces) as a single parameter. When you pass it to `subprocess` without the parameter `shell=True`, the argument is passed as-is to the pdflatex subprocess, and the filename itself does not start or end with '"', so it does not exist. The program pdflatex probably exits with this code since it cannot find the filename.

Try the following:

```
tex.callSystemCommand(['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-shell-escape', filename + '.tex'])
```

Also, in the example you showed to work (with `os.system`), you didn't include the addition of `.tex` to the filename, so it depends on how you provide it to the python script, and this may be the solution:

```
tex.callSystemCommand(['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-shell-escape', filename ])
```

Comment: Works now. But anyway it would have been great if there was a way to print out the actual command that is executed. Then I would have probably been able to solve it on my own.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode',
                     '-shell-escape', filename + '.tex'], shell=True)
```

Comment: it is incorrect to use a list argument with `shell=True` on Unix. There is no redirection and therefore it is pointless to call `.communicate()` here. `subprocess.call()` from the question is fine here.